# Brew install class-dump doesn't work. How to fix it?

Tags: macos, homebrew

My mac is having MacOS 10.12.4 (Sierra). And I have installed homebrew using command line. This is what look like when I run "brew config" command.

[image]

Then I wanted to install class-dump using following command.
"brew install class-dump". But when it gives me following error. Can some one tell me the reason and what should I do?

[image]

Comment: There’s no Homebrew package for `class-dump` so it’s normal you can’t install it.

Comment: It seems homebrew has removed it later on.. So I manually installed the class dump.

Comment: @bfontaine There *was* a `class-dump` package in Homebrew. But, it's not there any more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by installing class-dump manually without using home brew. I downloaded the class-dump in using this [link](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/). Then copy the class-dump file to the following location "/usr/local/bin". Then all works fine

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one liner for the lazy people if you already have `wget`:

```
$ wget -qO- http://stevenygard.com/download/class-dump-3.5.tar.gz  | tar xvz - -C /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: You may need to do `mv /usr/local/bin/class-dump-3.5/class-dump /usr/local/bin/class-dump` after to get it in your PATH.